# How to monitor the health/status/Activity/Any Error/Failure Log of the application

Tags: java, monitoring, dashboard

We are working in Java based web application.

We need to create a dashboard for the application admin to monitor the status of the application.

It will basically like whats happening in the application e.g. log of any activity we want to keep track of, any errors, reason for failue to upload some file. Also if there is any planned activity in the system admin should be able to see if it has taken place or not etc stuff.

What should be the database design? Shall I keep only one table for all activites that need to be tracked and shown on dashboard or a single table for all activity?

As well how do I log such activities?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use log4j (or similar) with a syslog appender. Syslog has to run as a deamon on the machine and you have good dashboards for supervision/monitoring and so on. You may also connect a network of syslog deamons to gather information on multiple machines.

Another complementary solution is to use JMX and monitoring tools like Shinken, Hyperic, Nagios, etc.